# cmake will not compile to C++ 11 standard

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

I'm new to C++ and have been struggling with compiling/making/linking/building/whatever, lets see if somebody can help me out.  I did some searches and found other people with similar problems but I tried their solutions with no luck, so here goes:

A simple c++ program that uses C++ 11 functionality such as uniform initialization, threads, `to_string`, etc... generates errors that *"xxx" was not declared in the scope*.  Specifically right now I'd like to use `to_string`, and using it in the `std` namespace or specifically `std::to_string` creates the error *"to_string" is not a member of STD*.  So clearly it's not compiling with C++ 11.

So here's my make file:

```
#####################################
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (raspicam_test)
find_package(raspicam REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV)

IF  ( OpenCV_FOUND AND raspicam_CV_FOUND)
        MESSAGE(STATUS "COMPILING OPENCV TESTS")
        add_executable (main main.cpp)
        #target_compile_features(main PRIVATE cxx_range_for)
        set_property(TARGET main PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
        target_link_libraries (main ${raspicam_CV_LIBS})
ELSE()
        MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "OPENCV NOT FOUND IN YOUR SYSTEM")
ENDIF()
#####################################
```

As you can see I'm playing around with OpenCV on a raspberry pi.  But without the C++11 functions the program compiles and runs no issues.  But I would like to add threads and other goodies from C++11.  I added the line `set_property(TARGET main PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED 11)` according to the CMAKE documentation:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html

And it made no difference in the errors generated.  I did it first without the `_REQUIRED` and then with it.  I also tried `target_compile_features()` instead but CMAKE returned with "unknown CMAKE command".

Other details:
-Compiling on a raspberry pi 3 running debian jessie
-CXX compiler is GNU 4.9.2
-CMAKE 3.0.2

Comment: I realized that I only had CMAKE 3.0.2 and the documentation I linked was for CMAKE 3.1, maybe it doesn't support that CXX_STANDARD property?  What I ended up using was "set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")" , which worked for me.  Would a later version of CMAKE worked with the set_property method?  Does one have a benefit over the other?

Comment: CXX_STANDARD was new in 3.1 https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/release/3.1.0.html#properties

Comment: FYI part of your difficulties lie in C++03 being the default for GCC 4.x with 4.7 being the first C++11 capable. When you have GCC 5.x then C++11 will be the default and GCC 6.x C++14 will be the default.

Comment: @MattSchuchard GCC5 still used `gnu++03` for C++ by default, but `gnu11` for C. GCC6 switched to `gnu++14` as default C++ mode.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In CMake versions **earlier than 3.1**, we use

```
 add_compile_options(-std=c++11) # CMake 2.8.12 or newer
```

to add compile options to the compiler call as described in the [CMake Docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html).

That's propably not as portable as the one in Alvaro's answer, but it's more readable and since you are on you RasPi, I guess, GCC and Clang as target compilers will do.

**Edit:** For the sake of completeness: In CMake version **3.1 and newer**, if you want to force C++11, you need the following lines:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) # C++11...
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) #...is required...
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF) #...without compiler extensions like gnu++11
```

This enables the options for all targets following this declaration during compilation. If you want to control this more fine-grained, see Alvaro's answer or the CMake Docs of `set_taget_properties()`, which then looks something like this:

```
set_target_properties(myTarget PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 11
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
    CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
)
```

**Edit:** But beware that C++11 support in GCC 4 is not complete and there might be things that behave differently from the defined standard.

Comment: There is an even more modern facility: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html You can request particular features and cmake will automatically provide flags for your compiler.

Comment: @IlyaPopov: Thanks for the hint. Not sure if it is more modern, though. It's more fine-grained for sure but it was introduced simultaneously with `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` and friends. ... Also, I tried to find a feature keyword for this specific case (for using `to_string`) but could not find one. Did I miss it? I would like to add this to the answer but only if I can put in something specific.

Comment: outdated? It doesn't work for a android gradle project with native c++ code.  The latest version of CMake is 3.15 now.

Comment: @zwcloud No idea about Android or Gradle but `CXX_STANDARD` and `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` still work with CMake 3.15.

Answer (score 4):

CMake add support for `CXX_STANDARD` and `CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` properties on 3.1 version.
`CXX_STANDARD`: Take one of `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` values and they are `98, 11 and 14`.
If you pass `CXX_STANDARD 11` and you compiler do not support c++11 
`CXX_STANDARD` become 98 automatically and cmake do not give you any
error if `CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` is `OFF` or unset.
If your set `CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED "ON" CXX_STANDARD` specific value become as a required property to build and cmake handle this.

In orde to use `CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG` you nedd to include CheckCXXCompilerFlag module:

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
    message(STATUS "${COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11}")
else(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "${COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11}")
endif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
```

If you have a old cmake you need handle complicate and not portable flags
from compilers sush as:

```
function(suported_compilers)
  if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "GNU")
    execute_process(
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -dumpversion OUTPUT_VARIABLE GCC_VERSION)
    if(NOT(GCC_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 4.7 OR GCC_VERSION VERSION_EQUAL 4.7))
      message(FATAL_ERROR "${PROJECT_NAME} requires g++ 4.7 or greater.")
    endif(NOT(GCC_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 4.7 OR GCC_VERSION VERSION_EQUAL 4.7))
  elseif("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "Clang")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")
  else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Your compiler is supported in the build set?, please "
                  "contact the maintainer.")
  endif()
endfunction(suported_compilers)
function(set_targets_compilers_flags target_list)
  suported_compilers()
  foreach(tg ${target_list})
    if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU" OR "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
      set_target_properties(${tg} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-g -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Werror")
    elseif("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
      set_target_properties(${tg} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/W4 /WX /EHsc")
    endif()
  endforeach()
endfunction(set_targets_compilers_flags)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the current cmake release is 3.10, I thought it may be appropriate to identify the newer method.  While the suggestion to use add_compiler_

For anyone looking here at a more modern version of cmake (3.1+), The most appropriate answer is not to identify a version of a given compiler but to let CMAKE know what features need to be available.

```
target_compile_features(engine
    PRIVATE cxx_range_for
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

I always enable c++11 in my code using CMake this way:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
```

My compiler is gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, however in my workplace I also use other versions and this approach always works.

EDIT (to avoid variable overwriting):

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

Comment: This overrides the variable which the user might have set to some custom value already in his shell. If you want to use it, do it this way: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-std=c++11")` ... but in general, prefer a more "modern" approach like `add_compile_option()` or the `CXX_STANDARD` variable. :)