# Set libstdc++ implementation version using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, c++14, libstdc++

Consider the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(demo CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
add_executable(demo main.cpp)
target_compile_features(demo PUBLIC cxx_std_14)
```

And now the following `main.cpp` c++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cout << "__cplusplus=" << __cplusplus << std::endl;
  std::vector<int> v;
  // junk code to prevent g++ from removing code (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release)
  v.reserve(10);
  v.push_back(42);
  v.shrink_to_fit();

  return v[argc-1];
}
```

If I run the above on my Debian bullseye machine (with backports). Here is what I find out after configuration && build:

```
% cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release . && make
```

Leads to:

```
% nm demo | grep cxx17
0000000000001370 W _ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE17_M_realloc_insertIJiEEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EEDpOT_
```

However:

```
% ./demo
__cplusplus=201402
```

How come I see `cxx17` related symbol when I make sure to compile with c++14 only flags ?

---

For reference:

```
% g++ --version
g++ (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
```

and

```
% cmake --version
cmake version 3.22.0
```

Comment: Have you tried to follow [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37631452/3440745) for specify strict settings of the C++ standard? It sets variable `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` to ON for actually require a standard and sets variable `CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS` to OFF for avoid compiler-specific extensions.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Well spotted ! The cmakelists.txt is now clearer: the flag -std=c++14 is now clearly visible in the verbose output. the issue still remains.

Comment: So your problem that even with `-std=c++14` gcc still links with some cxx17 symbols. CMake is absolutely unrelated with that. As for `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` and related variables, they denotes only to C++ **standard**: your code will be compiled (and linked) according to rules defined in the corresponding standard. The option `-std=c++14` is about C++ standard too. A C++ standard specifies what method `vector::resize()` should do on abstract level. But a C++ standard doesn't specify which functions should be used by that method, so a compiler is free to take these functions from cxx17 namespace.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'll have to accept this as definite answer. But in my mind, I would have expected the opposite: Code compiled with `-std=c++17` may rely on `cxx14` implementation details...